# Unable to POST Values And Create a Derived Value in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I am new to Django and still learning. Currently, I have a running code below which allows me to input data but I am unable to POST it to DB. I am not sure what I've done wrong.

**Model**

```
class ManHour(models.Model):

    station_choices = (
       ('alpha','A'),
       ('beta', 'B'),
       ('gamma','G'),
       )


    station = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=station_choices,
    )

    date      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ops_1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3, default = 1)
    ops_2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3, default = 1)
    ops_3 = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3, default = 1)
```

**Form**

```
from django import forms
from webapp.models import ManHour

class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ManHour
        fields = ['station', 'ops_1', 'ops_2', 'ops_3']
```

**Views**

```
def form_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        properties_Form = InputForm(request.POST)
        if properties_Form.is_valid():
            properties_Form.save()

            return redirect('home')
    context ={}
    context.update(csrf(request))
    context['request'] = request
    context['form']= InputForm()
    return render(request, "form.html", context)
```

**HTML**

```
{% block content %}

<form target="upload_frame" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}<br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="submit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Given the above code I am not sure why I am unable to post values to DB.

My second question is that I want to create a derived field that sums `ops1` and `ops2` and I want it show to user. I tried adding another field using code below but I am getting error of unrecognized fields in save function.

```
class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ManHour
        fields = ['station', 'ops_1', 'ops_2', 'ops_3']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.total_ops = self.ops_1 + self.ops_2
    return super(InputForm, self).save()
```

I am getting an error `instance of InputForm has no ops_1 member`.

So I've two two question

- Why am I unable to make POSTs to DB?
- How can I create an evaluated field and show user?

**Update**

Scripts after applying changes:

**Model**

```
from django.db import models

class ManHour(models.Model):

    station_choices = (
       ('alpha','A'),
       ('beta', 'B'),
       ('gamma','G'),
       )


    station = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=station_choices,
    )

    date  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ops_1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3, default = 1)
    ops_2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3, default = 1)
    ops_3 = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3, default = 1)
```

**Form**

```
from django import forms
from webapp.models import ManHour

class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ManHour
        fields = ['station', 'ops_1', 'ops_2', 'ops_3']
```

**Admin**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ManHour
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(ManHour)
```

**Views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate 
from django.contrib import messages
from .form import InputForm
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required



# Create your views here.

def home_view(request, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {})

def login_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
                return redirect('form')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request = request,
                    template_name = "login.html",
                    context={"form":form})
                    
@login_required(login_url='login')
def form_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        properties_Form = InputForm(request.POST)
        if properties_Form.is_valid():
            instance = properties_Form.save()
            total_ops = instance.ops_1 + instance.ops_2
            redirect("%s?total_ops=%s" % (reverse('home'), total_ops))
    context = {}
    context['request'] = request
    context['form']= InputForm()
    return render(request, "form.html", context)
```

**base.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Budget Data</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css'%}", type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %} 
    {% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

**login.HTML**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**form.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Form{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<form target="upload_frame" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}<br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="submit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**URLS.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path
from pages import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home_view, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', views.login_request, name='login'),
    path('form/', views.form_page, name='form'),
```

I've updated the question to make changes as per the answer, however I am unable to view the evaluated field and I am unable to POST data to db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get only data of form then you can access its through [**`cleaned_data`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data)([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data)).

```
class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ManHour
        fields = ['station', 'ops_1', 'ops_2', 'ops_3']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.total_ops = self.cleaned_data.get("ops_1", 0) + self.cleaned_data.get("ops_2", 0)
        return super(InputForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```

If you wand to modify **instance** first of all you need to call [**`super(InputForm, self).save(commit=False)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) ([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)) method to get instance.

---

Also your form can't be valid. Because `station` field has `max_length=3`. And some choices are length 4 and 5.
It must be:

```
station = models.CharField(
    max_length=5,
    choices=station_choices,
)
```

---

**Update**

If you want to do some calculation with the form data and provide it to the `home` view you can use **GET** parameters for that, like the following:

```
from django.urls import reverse

def form_page(request):
    context = {}
    try:
        man_hour = ManHour.objects.get(pk=request.GET.get("pk"))
    except ManHour.DoesNotExist:
        man_hour = None

    if man_hour:
        context["total_ops"] = man_hour.ops_1 + man_hour.ops_2

    if request.method == 'POST':
        properties_Form = InputForm(request.POST, instance=man_hour)
        if properties_Form.is_valid():
            obj = properties_Form.save()
            return redirect("%s?pk=%s" % (reverse('form'), obj.pk))
    else:
        context['form']= InputForm(instance=man_hour)

    return render(request, "form.html", context)
```

In HTML add url `action` to the form tag to prevent opening in new tab and for calculation you can use `jQuery`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" async></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This page is loaded with jquery.</p>
      

        <form target="upload_frame" action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}<br>
            <input type="text" name="total_ops" value="{{ total_ops }}" disabled><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="submit">
        </form>


        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('input[name="ops_1"],input[name="ops_2"],input[name="ops_3"]').change(function() {
                    let ops_1 = parseFloat($('input[name="ops_1"]').val());
                    let ops_2 = parseFloat($('input[name="ops_2"]').val());
                    let ops_3 = parseFloat($('input[name="ops_3"]').val());
                    $('input[name="total_ops"]').val(ops_1 + ops_2 + ops_3);

                })
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Actually you don't need to override the `save()` method of `ModelForm`.

Comment: I am unable to POST data to db after making the suggested changes before updated answer. In updated answer I am getting syntax error at `context{}`

Comment: @Lopez, remove this line context.update(csrf(request)).

Comment: I am still getting the similar error `invalid syntax`

Comment: @Lopez, A brace was too short at this line `redirect("%s?total_ops=%s" % (reverse('home'), total_ops))`, not it must working.

Comment: Please review my edit in question. I am unable to get the desired results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231024/discussion-between-nksm-and-lopez).